# Intercept Copy and Paste with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, copy-paste

Is it possible to intercept global copy and paste in OS X with an AppleScript? Or would I have to have some intermediary step that would trigger the AppleScript to read the clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way I do it in Applescript is with the following command:

```
get the clipboard
```

You could of course then do stuff like setting it to a variable and displaying it:

```
set xyz to the clipboard
display alert (xyz as text)
```

Hope that helps!

Elliott

Comment: @Elliott, that does help, thank you. Now how would I get this script to run the moment I copied something to the clipboard?

Comment: Hmm, that's a tricky question. I'm afraid I don't have a great answer for you on that. The best way to do something similar if you have OSX 10.6 is create a service using automator, put your applescript in as part of the action, and then assign it to a keyboard shortcut. That would get rid of some of the intermediate steps...

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll look into that. Thanks for the help!